# How can I detect and report Unicode code points that aren't legal for interchange using Perl?

Tags: perl, unicode, character-encoding

I'm using Perl to process hundreds of thousands of plain-text files in the UTF-8 character encoding scheme of Unicode. These plain-text documents are computer evidence in the legal discovery process. I don't have the luxury of either replacing them or ignoring them.

My problem is that some of these files are polluted with garbage: encoding-corrupted text, invalid binary data, etc. I need to be able to detect and report exactly what's wrong with these supposed plain-text documents *in Unicode terms.* In other words, I must identify the presence of specific categories of invalid Unicode code points:  Unicode non-characters, surrogates, and non-Unicode characters. It's not enough just to work around them, which I know how to do.

Using Perl 5.14, how can I detect and report Unicode code points that aren't legal for interchange? I'm mostly just looking for hints on how to get started.

Comment: Even if there's no ready-made solution, that shouldn't be terribly hard to rig up yourself. UTF-8 is fairly straight-forward. Make sure to check for "shortest-possible" encoding, and that the resulting values are valid Unicode codepoints (this excludes surrogates). I think a page or two of code can do that.

Comment: How do you define which code points are “legal”? For example, Private Use code points are not recommended for public information interchange, but they are still “legal” (valid, conforming), even though their meaning can be based on private agreements only. Moreover, it sounds that you really want to detect *malformed data* like byte combinations that are not allowed in UTF-8 – and thus do not identify *any* code point.

Comment: My first thought is to suggest that you look at the [Encode module](http://perldoc.perl.org/Encode.html), but you probably know about that if you can already work around bad data.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I need to detect both [invalid UTF-8 byte sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Invalid_byte_sequences) and [invalid code points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Invalid_code_points) (i.e., code points that are not valid for data interchange). Anything that's *wrong* with the text Unicode-wise, I need to detect it and report it in a forensic way.

Comment: I think simple Encode::decode('UTF-8', $octets, sub { say $_[0] }) is a nice starting point.
See:
https://metacpan.org/module/Encode#UTF-8-vs.-utf8-vs.-UTF8
https://metacpan.org/module/Encode#Handling-Malformed-Data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, find encoding errors, then find undesired code points.

The latter is easy since there are Unicode properties to identify them. (See below)

To report the errors precisely, you might want to write your own decoder to find the UTF-8 errors.

```
sub bytes_to_hex { join ' ', map { sprintf '%02X', $_ } unpack 'C*', $_[0] }

my @errors;
my @warns;
my $output = '';
for ($input) {
   while (!/\G \z /xgc) {
      my $pos = pos;

      if (/\G (
         (?: [\x00-\x7F]
         |   [\xC0-\xDF][\x80-\xBF]
         |   [\xE0-\xEF][\x80-\xBF]{2}
         |   [\xF0-\xF7][\x80-\xBF]{3}
         |   [\xF8-\xFB][\x80-\xBF]{4}
         |   [\xFC-\xFD][\x80-\xBF]{5}
         )
      ) /xgc) {
         my $bytes = $1;
         my @bytes = unpack 'C*', $bytes;
         my $hex_bytes = bytes_to_hex($bytes);

         if ($bytes =~ /^
            (?: [\xC0-\xC1]
            |   \xE0[\x80-\x9F]
            |   \xF0[\x80-\x8F]
            |   \xF8[\x80-\x87]
            |   \xFC[\x80-\x83]
            )
         /x) {
            push @warns, "Overlong encoding $hex_bytes at pos $pos";
         }

         if ($bytes =~ /^[\xF8-\xFD]/) {
            push @warns, "Defunct 5 or 6 byte sequence $hex_bytes at pos $pos";
         }

         my $code_point_ord = @bytes == 1
            ? $bytes[0]
            : $bytes[0] & ( 0x7F >> @bytes );
         $code_point_ord = ( $code_point_ord << 6 ) | ( $_ & 0x3F )
            for @bytes[ 1..$#bytes ];
         my $code_point_hex = sprintf('U+%05X', $code_point_ord);
         my $code_point = chr($code_point_ord);

         if ($code_point_ord >= 0x110000) {
            push @errors, "Non-Unicode $code_point_hex at pos $pos";
         } else {
            push @warns, "Surrogate $code_point_hex at pos $pos"
               if $code_point =~ /\p{Cs}/;
            push @warns, "Private use $code_point_hex at pos $pos"
               if $code_point =~ /\p{Co}/;
            push @warns, "Unassigned $code_point_hex at pos $pos"
               if $code_point =~ /\p{Cn}/;

            $output .= $code_point;
         }
      }

      elsif (/\G (
         (?: [\xC0-\xDF]
         |   [\xE0-\xEF][\x80-\xBF]{0,1}
         |   [\xF0-\xF7][\x80-\xBF]{0,2}
         |   [\xF8-\xFB][\x80-\xBF]{0,3}
         |   [\xFC-\xFD][\x80-\xBF]{0,4}
         )
      ) /xgc) {
         my $bytes = $1;
         my $hex_bytes = bytes_to_hex($bytes);
         push @errors, "Incomplete sequence $hex_bytes at pos $pos";
      }

      elsif (/\G ( [\x80-\xBF] ) /xgc) {
         my $byte = $1;
         my $hex_byte = bytes_to_hex($byte);
         push @errors, "Unexpected continuation byte $hex_byte at pos $pos";
      }

      elsif (/\G ( [\xFE-\xFF] ) /xgc) {
         my $byte = $1;
         my $hex_byte = bytes_to_hex($byte);
         push @errors, "Invalid byte $hex_byte at pos $pos";
      }
      else {
         die "Bug";
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile under `use strict`. It reports, `Global symbol "$code_point" requires explicit package name at ikegami.pl line 47.
ikegami.pl had compilation errors.` The offending line is `my $code_point = chr($code_point);`.

Comment: @Jim Monty, Fixed. Not tested.

Comment: Can you please explain the bit-fiddling lines? If you're just decoding bytes to UTF-8 characters, why not simply use `Encode::decode()`?

Comment: How does the undocumented bit-fiddling versus using `Encode::decode()` make for better error reporting? I don't understand.

Comment: To report the errors precisely. The purpose of Encode::decode isn't to fulfill legal requirements of documenting changes to evidence. If you want precise reporting, you have to look further than the builtin function.

Comment: I was looking for code that precisely does this. Is this code also on cpan?